# How can I handle Json response which have a Timestamp using the Gson ?? java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, json, apache, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an object which have a 3 Timestamp fields and i want to consume a json response using Gson but i have got an  Invalid time zone indicator ' '.
so this is out put :

```
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2017-11-30 15:19:37
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:84)

... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:245)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:245)
... 32 more
```

And this is my Json response :

```
{
"status": "OK",
"data": {
    "due_days": 10,

    "attested_at": null,
    "updated_at": "2017-12-01 11:59:56",
    "automatic_collection": {
        "amount": null,
        "delay_days": null
    },
    "currency": "SEK",
        "collector_paid_sum": 0,
        "remaining_sum": 0
    },
    "id": "zeY37WJ",
    "reminder_fee": 60.0,
    "interest_rate": 8.5,
    "state": "Unattested",
    "due_date": "2017-12-11",
    "automatic_reminders_settings": [],
    "invoice_fee_vat": 0,
    "invoice_date": "2017-12-01",
    "reminder_count": 0,
    "interest_fee": 0.0,
    "invoice_no": 0,
    "created_at": "2017-11-30 15:21:08",
    "total_sum": 0.0,
    "delivery_method": "Letter",
    "remaining_sum": 0.0,
    "flags": [],
}
```

}

THis my Gson code :

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new DateDeserializer()).create();
    invoiceModels = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get("data").toString(), InvoiceModel[].class);
```

and this is my DateDeserializer

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
public Date deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
  String date = element.getAsString();

  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'");
  format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

  try {
      return format.parse(date);
  } catch (ParseException exp) {
      System.out.println("Failed to parse Date:"+ exp);
      return null;
  }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you explicitly include the timezone pattern fragment `Z` in `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'"`. Your data doesn't include any timezone, judging from your example.

Setting the timezone on the formatter doesn't mean it will ignore the timezone-part of the parsed string. Instead, it will be used when timezone data is abscent.

Answer (score -1):

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new DateDeserializer()). **.setDateFormat(DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_FORMAT.getPattern())**
create();
```

will work